# Разворачивание приложения в docker одной командой

Tags: docker, composer, docker-compose, dockerfile

Стоит задача развернуть приложение в докере одной командой `docker-compose -up --build`, подскажите как можно запустить команду `composer install` во время развертывания , если я указываю в dockerfiles строку `CMD composer install`, то папка vendor появляется, но не запускается контейнер php с сервером, как еще можно запустить `composer install`?

## Dockerfiles:

```
FROM php:7.3.24-apache-stretch

RUN apt-get update

#Install tools required for build stage
RUN apt-get install -fyqq \
    bash curl wget rsync ca-certificates openssl ssh git tzdata openntpd \
    libxrender1 fontconfig libc6 \
    mariadb-client gnupg binutils-gold autoconf \
    g++ gcc gnupg libgcc1 linux-headers-amd64 make python


#Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- \
    --filename=composer \
    --install-dir=/usr/local/bin && \
    composer


#Install additional PHP libraries
RUN docker-php-ext-install bcmath pdo_mysql

#Install libraries for compiling GD, then build it
RUN apt-get install -fyqq libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev libpng16-16 libpng-dev libjpeg62-turbo libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install gd \
    && apt-get remove -fyqq libfreetype6-dev libpng-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev

#Add ZIP archives support
RUN apt-get install -fyqq zip libzip-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip \
    && apt-get remove -fyqq

WORKDIR /var/www/html

CMD composer install
```

## docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.5"

services:
  php:
    build:
      context: php
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html

  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:10.4
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123456
      MYSQL_DATABASE: task_db
    volumes:
      - ./databases:/var/lib/mysql 

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mariadb
```

Comment: скорее всего должно быть `RUN composer install`, а в CMD уже запуск сервера

Comment: ошибка ```Composer could not find a composer.json file in /var/www/html
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
ERROR: Service 'php' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c composer install' returned a non-zero code: 1 ```, хотя при варианте `CMD composer install` папка vendor и composer.lock появляться

Comment: Достаточно странная задача если это не деплой. Если вы хотите запускать  composer install  в Dockerfile то вам предварительно нужно скопировать  composer.json в создаваемый вами образ, однако в этом не будет никакого смысла в вашем случае ибо вы монтируете папку с рабочей машины в контейнер и попросту затрете работу композера. Если вы указываете в CMD то это по факту не относится непосредственно к --build, ведь CMD отрабатывает в момент запуска контейнера, а не в момент сборки.  Но раз  уж вам нужно. Возможно вам нужно восползоваться ENTRYPOINT для выполнения подобных команд.